# Cryptarithmetic puzzle (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I was asked to write a Prolog code to solve the cryptarithmetic puzzle, using "generate and test". For example I get `solve([R,O,B],[B,E,R,T],[N,O,R,E,S])` and I need to find an assign for the letters. 
So I wrote this code:

```
sum(List1,List2,SumList) :-
    append(List1,List2,List3),
    append(List3,SumList,AllList),
    assign([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],AllList),
    add_zero(List1,List1Z),
    add_zero(List2,List2Z),
    add_zero(SumList,SumListZ),
    name(Num1,List1Z),
    name(Num2,List2Z),
    name(SumNum,SumListZ),
    SumNum is Num1+Num2,
    !.

remove(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
remove(X,[_|Ys],Res) :-
    remove(X,Ys,Res).

assign(Digits,[X|Tail]) :-
    nonvar(X),
    !,
    assign(Digits,Tail).
assign(Digits,[X|Tail]) :-
    remove(X,Digits,D1),
    assign(D1,Tail).
assign(_,[]) :-
    !.

add_zero([X|Tail1],[Y|Tail2]) :-
    !,
    Y is X+48,
    add_zero(Tail1,Tail2).
add_zero([],[]) :-
    !.
```

But I have a bug and I can't find it... can you help me?

Comment: a very closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925285/faster-implementation-of-verbal-arithmetic-in-prolog

Comment: Hello this is an old question thread but I have a problem understanding it.

    add_zero([X|Tail1],[Y|Tail2]) :-
    !,
    Y is X+48,
    add_zero(Tail1,Tail2).

Why Y is X+48 ? What does 'add_zero' function do here? 

Could you please help me understand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in the second clause of `remove/3` you are not keeping the item which is not removed.
It should read:

```
remove(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|Res]):-
    remove(X,Ys,Res).
```

I tried your code with SEND + MORE = MONEY and it worked fine after fixing that procedure.

However it did not find a solution for ROB + BERT = NORES... According to [this site](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/llp/crypt.html), which has many solvers, your equation has no solution.

Comment: There's no solution to rob+bert=nores: http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/llp/crypt.html