# How to Solve Cryptarithmetic Puzzle in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I have to write a Prolog program for solving a cryptarithmetic puzzle.

I need to write a function solve([A, M, P, D, Y]) which assigns the variables [A, M, P, D, Y] to values from 0 to 9 so that it satisfies the equation AM+PM=DAY. Each variable is assigned to a different value, and A, P, and D cannot be equal to 0.

I started writing this function, but ran into problems running my program. I set the restrictions of A, P, and D not being zero. As I was going through the algorithm, I realized that D has to be 1, so I defined that in the beginning of my program. I defined two different variables for M (M1 and M2) and set them equal to each other, since the different M’s in the puzzle should be assigned to the same value. I assigned locations to the different variables and added them up based on the puzzle. I accounted for any variables being carried with carry in variables. My program compiles but the function does not execute.

```
solve([A, M1, M2, P, D, Y]):- D is 1,
A/=0,
P/=0,
D/=0,
M1 = M2,
select(M1, [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], R1),
select(M2, R1, R2),
Y is (M1+M2) mod 10,
C1 is (M1+M2) // 10,
select(Y, R2, R3),
select(A, R3, R4),
select(P, R4, R5),
select(D, R5, R6),
A is (A+P+C1) mod 10,
D is (A+P+C1)// 10.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my variable definitions? Do I need to define two different M variables, or is one sufficient?

Comment: Why are you checking A,P,D at start ? You need to assign values to A,P,D then check if they are different from zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution for your puzzle. We simply rely on PROLOG's backtracking. We select all variables first, then check the puzzle conditions. I don't think that you need to define two Ms.

```
solve([A,M,P,D,Y]):- 
select(A,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],WA), % W means Without
not(A=0),
select(M,WA,WMA),
select(P,WMA,WMAP),
not(P=0),
select(D,WMAP,WMAPD),
not(D=0),
select(Y,WMAPD,WMAPDY),
DAY is 100*D+10*A+Y,
AM  is 10*A+M,
PM  is 10*P+M,
DAY is AM+PM.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. Also, is there a way to solve it using the mod 10 way (as I attempted implementing in my original post)?

Comment: I think you can do it with mod 10 , but in order to find Y for example (using mod 10), we need to get DAY first, then Y is simply DAY mod 10,A is (DAY div 10) mod 10,D is DAY div 100,same goes for AM and PM. But DAY is a three digit number, hence the select will be from [100,101,...,99+99] for DAY,[10,11,...,99] for AM,PM (2 digits ) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, why did you add a WA (without A) variable? There are duplicates of As and Ms.

Comment: Ehem with select(A,[0,1....,9],WA) we get some list that doesn't contain the value ( I named it WA ) for A. Also A in DAY and in AM must have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You write:  "My program compiles but the function does not execute: "

```
solve([A, M1, M2, P, D, Y]):- D is 1,
    A/=0,
```

No wonder. First of all, there's no `/=` operator in Prolog. I assume you meant `\=`. But `A \= B` means "A can not be unified with B". In your case `B` is 0, but `A` is a yet not set logical variable. It can be unified with *anything*. You should only use `\=` to *check* inequality, *after* all logvars involved had been instantiated!

So, `A \= 0` ***fails***. (Another thing is, `M1=M2` is superfluous, you can just use `M` throughout).

A general tool to solve such puzzles is [unique selection from narrowing domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11011680/849891):

```
selectM([A|As],S,Z):- select(A,S,S1),selectM(As,S1,Z).
selectM([],Z,Z).
```

With it, your puzzle is just

```
solve([A,M,P,D,Y]):-
  selectM([A,P,D],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],R),     % R is the remaining domain
  selectM([M,Y],[0|R],_),                     % don't care what remains
  10*(A+P)+M+M =:= 100*D+10*A+Y.
```

---

You have a right idea of finding out the assignments before searching, where possible. Using your approach, it could be written as

```
solve([A,M,P,D,Y]):-    
  selectM([M,A],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],R),
  A =\= 0,
  Y  is (M+M) mod 10,     % AM+PM=DAY
  C1 is (M+M) // 10,
  A  is (A+P+C1) mod 10,
  D  is (A+P+C1) // 10,
  selectM([P,D,Y],R,_),   % ensure all are different
  p =\= 0, D =\= 0.
```

Again, we *must* select `A` before testing its value.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have posted, I would like to present a slightly different take on this.

The following solution uses GNU Prolog and its **CLP(FD)** constraints. Such constraints are available in all widely used Prolog systems.

```
solution(Vs) :-
        Vs = [A,M,P,D,Y],
        fd_domain(Vs, 0, 9),
                   A*10 + M
                 + P*10 + M
        #= D*100 + A*10 + Y,
        fd_all_different(Vs),
        A #\= 0,
        P #\= 0,
        D #\= 0.
```

I now highlight a few **key advantages** of using CLP(FD) constraints in this case.

First, it is obvious that we can model all requirements in an extremely **straight-forward** way with such constraints. The program is really an almost verbatim translation of your task to built-in relations:

- > I need to write a function solve([A, M, P, D, Y])

  I used `solution/1` instead of the imperative `solve/1`, because the **predicate** makes sense in *all directions*, including specific instances where all variables are already **bound** to concrete integers. In such cases, we can use the predicate to **verify** solutions. Calling it "solve" does not make sense in cases where the puzzle is already completely solved. Also, we can use the predicate to *complete* partially instantiated solutions. In Prolog, it is good practice to *avoid* imperatives for predicate names.
- > which assigns the variables [A, M, P, D, Y] to values from 0 to 9

  This is stated via `fd_domain(Vs, 0, 9)`.
- > so that it satisfies the equation AM+PM=DAY.

  The equation is thus `A*10 + M + P*10 + M #= D*100 + A*10 + Y`.
- > Each variable is assigned to a different value

  This is expressed by the built-in constraint `fd_all_different/1`.
- > and A, P, and D cannot be equal to 0.

  This is stated via `A #\= 0` etc.

Second, we can use the most general query to study the effects of **constraint propagation**:

```
| ?- solution([).

Vs = [_#3(2..8),_#24(5..8),9,1,_#87(0:2..6)]
```

or, put differently:

```
| ?- solution([A,M,P,D,Y]).

A = _#3(2..8)
D = 1
M = _#24(5..8)
P = 9
Y = _#87(0:2..6)
```

This confirms what you say: `D` is *necessarily* 1 in this puzzle. And this also shows several other interesting things which go beyond what you found: `P` is *necessarily* 9. Moreover, quite strict bounds hold for `M`, and the domains of `A` and `Y` have also been pruned significantly.

This shows that constraint propagation has significantly **reduced** the search space.

What do concrete solutions look like? Here are a few examples:

```
| ?- solution(Vs), fd_labeling(Vs).

Vs = [2,5,9,1,0] ? ;

Vs = [2,7,9,1,4] ? ;

Vs = [2,8,9,1,6] ?

yes
```

Third, you can run different **labeling options** to try various search strategies for exploring the solution space, *without* the need to change or recompile the program.

Finally,a significantly reduced search space typically yields **much faster** programs. I leave it as an exercise to run a few benchmarks that show how much faster the CLP(FD)-based version is in this case.

See **[clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)** for more information about this important declarative paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem are the multiple 'assignments' to D. First D get bound to 1, after that cannot change value (Prolog use unification, not assignment). Then both

```
...
select(D, R5, R6),
...
D is (A+P+C1)// 10.
```

will fail when D is different than 1