# Prolog - All different list not counting "_" variable

Tags: list, prolog

I need to do a function in Prolog that, given a list, check if every member is different. The only particularity is that it must not count "_" variables.
Here is an example of what I want :

```
unique([3,1,2]). 
> true

unique([3,1,2,_]).
> true

unique([3,1,2,_,_,_]).
> true

unique([3,1,2,1]).
> false

unique([3,1,2,1,_]).
> false
```

I already tried with the following function, using the predicate "var" to check if the variable is free or not, but it doesn't work :

```
element(X,[X|_]) :- !.
element(X,[_|Q]) :- element(X,Q).

unique([]).
unique([_,[]]).
unique([T,Q]) :- var(T), unique(Q), !.
unique([T|Q]) :- \+element(T,Q),unique(Q).
```

Thank you for your help

*PS: I'm using GProlog*

*PS2: I know that the function fd_all_different could work, but I'd rather implement it myself*

Comment: What should `unique([3,1,2,X,X]).` do?

Comment: Basically, I do not have this case in my program, so it doesn't matter

Comment: +1 for using this nice name in place of `all_different/1`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606600/772868).

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238931/772868) should your Prolog not have `dif/2` defined

Comment: A couple of typographical issues: `unique([_,[]]).` ==> `unique([_]).` and `unique([T,Q]) :- ...` ==> `unique([T|Q]) :- ...`.

Comment: @false Thanks it worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to @false:

For those who wonder how, here's the "unique" function :

```
dif(X,Y) :- X \== Y.

unique([]).
unique([T|Q]) :- maplist(dif(T), Q), unique(Q).
```