# Write a Prolog program that solves the following arithmetic puzzle

Tags: prolog, clpfd, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

```
  PYP
  CQB
 CBCW
-----
WXYPB
```

where each letter represents a unique digit from 0-9 and the value below the line represents the sum of those about it.

Comment: I've added the relevant tags: You will find there exactly what you want as "Send more money"

Answer (score 1):

Check out the *very* related question [Faster implementation of verbal arithmetic in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925285/faster-implementation-of-verbal-arithmetic-in-prolog).

Based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30346715/4609915), let's solve your specific equation using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
?- Eq = ([P,Y,P] + [C,Q,B] + [C,B,C,W] #= [W,X,Y,P,B]),
   crypt_arith_(Eq,Zs),
   labeling([],Zs).
Eq = ([9,3,9]+[8,7,5]+[8,5,8,1]#=[1,0,3,9,5]),
Zs = [9,3,8,7,5,1,0],
P  = 9,
Y  = 3,
C  = 8,
Q  = 7,
B  = 5,
W  = 1,
X  = 0 ;
false.
```