# Crypto-arithmetic puzzle solver using CLPFD Library

Tags: prolog, clpfd, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I have seen some examples of cyrptarithmetic puzzle solver using Prolog's clfpd library. For instance if I have a puzzle AM + PM = DAY, it can assign different set of values from 0 to 9 to different alphabets so that A*10+M + P*10+M = D*100+A*10+Y. I am trying to write a generalized version of it. Please note that I have very little experience with either Prolog or clfpd.

I intend to generate constraints based on input. For instance A*10+M + P*10+M = D*100+A*10+Y is to be generated based in input puzzle1([A,M]+[P,M]=[D,A,Y]). But I have no idea how to do it. I have written a Prolog function (called convert) which based on input creates a constraint. But its not working and I keep getting error

```
clpfd_expression' expected, found `convert([_818,_894])
```

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
%calculate correct multiplier
%For example if AM, multipler of A is 10 and of M is 1 
multiple(1,10). 
multiple(N,F) :-  
    N#>0, 
    N1 #= N-1, 
    multiple(N1,F1), 
    F #= 10 * F1.
%convert accepts input as a list. For instance [A,M]
%outputs a constraint of the form A*10 + M*1
convert([H|T], Ans):-
    length(T, Len),
    Len #= 0,
    Ans #= H * 1.

convert([H|T], Ans):-
    length([H|T], Len1),
    Len2 #= Len1-1,
    multiple(Len2,Multiplier),
    convert(T, Ans1),
    Ans #= Ans1 + H * Multiplier.

%add should imply constraint A*10+M+P*10+M=D*100+A*10+Y.
add(Exp1, Exp2, Exp3):-
    Exp1 + Exp2 #= Exp3.

puzzle1(As + Bs = Cs) :- 
   append([As,Bs,Cs],Ds),
   term_variables(Ds,Var),   %% this will get all Var
   Var ins 0..9, 
   all_different(Var), 
   Exp01 #= convert(As),
   Exp02 #= convert(Bs),
   Exp03 #= convert(Cs),
   add(Exp01, Exp02, Exp03),
   %add constraint first member of each list cant be asigned a value 0
   As #= [H1|_],
   Bs #= [H2|_],
   Cs #= [H3|_],
   H1 #\=0,
   H2 #\=0,
   H3 #\=0.
```

Can someone steer me in correct direction.

Comment: So, what is your desired behaviour? Can you post some examples?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929492/772868) for some inspiration

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30346715/4609915 previous answer of mine! What's 2 lose?-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.  First, convert/2 is a predicate with two arguments -- you cannot use it as a function. So, instead of

```
Exp01 #= convert(As)
```

simply write

```
convert(As, Exp01)
```

The other mistake is

```
As #= [H1|_]
```

Here you want to structurally decompose the list `As` and extract its first element. The way to do that is with simple unification, i.e.

```
As = [H1|_]
```

The difference is that `#=` implements (integer) arithmetic equality (meaning that it interprets both sides as arithmetic expressions), while `=` is pure symbolic manipulation, which is what you want here.

You can find a program similar to yours at http://eclipseclp.org/examples/cryptarith.ecl.txt

Comment: I was able to single out those mistakes with some debugging. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
%calculate correct multiplier
%For example if AM, multipler of A is 10 and of M is 1 
multiple(1,10). 
multiple(N,F) :-  
    N>0, 
    N1 is N-1, 
    multiple(N1,F1), 
    F is 10 * F1.
%convert accepts input as a list. For instance [A,M]
%outputs a constraint of the form A*10 + M*1
convert([H|T], Ans):-
    length(T, Len),
    Len = 0,
    Ans = H * 1.
convert([H|T], Ans):-
    length([H|T], Len1),
    Len2 is Len1-1,
    multiple(Len2,Multiplier),
    convert(T, Ans1),
    Ans = Ans1 + H * Multiplier.


puzzle1(As + Bs = Cs) :- 
   append([As,Bs,Cs],Ds),
   term_variables(Ds,Var),   %% this will get all Var
   Var ins 0..9, 
   all_different(Var),
   convert(As, Ans1),
   convert(Bs, Ans2),
   convert(Cs, Ans3),
   %Generates a constraint depending on the input
   %For instance if input is puzzle1([A,M] + [P,M] = [D,A,Y])
   %Output constraint = A*10 + M + P*10 + M  = D*100 + A*10 + Y 
   Ans1 + Ans2 #= Ans3,
   As = [H1|_],
   Bs = [H2|_],
   H1 #\=0,
   H2 #\=0,
   label(Var),
   write("Solution: "),
   write(As + Bs = Cs).


%puzzle1([A,M]+[P,M]=[D,A,Y]).
%puzzle1([A,M]+[I]=[O,K]).
%puzzle1([Y,O,U]+[A,R,E]=[D,O,N,E]).
%puzzle1([S,E,N,D]+[M,O,R,E]=[M,O,N,E,Y]).
%puzzle1([R,O,A,D]+[I,N]=[U,S,A]).
%puzzle1([B,I,K,E]+[F,O,R]=[R,I,D,E]).
```